# Filtering json data in ngfor with ngif ionic4

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, ionic-framework

i'm create ionic apps with angular 8, i try to display datas from json file and filter it with ngif in home.page.html, here's my code

```
<ion-slides class="links_slide" [options]="sliderConfig">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngIf="item.status === 'marketplace'">
    <ion-card class="list-container" (click)='webview()' [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+item.iconlink+')'">
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card-title class="label">{{ item.name }}</ion-card-title>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

and here's the json

```
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "status":"marketplace",
        "name": "Webstore",
        "link": "https://youthscarf.com",
        "iconlink": "http://atmoweb.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/ysweb.jpg"
    }
    {
        "id": "6",
        "status":"oa",
        "name": "Instagram Signature",
        "link": "https://instagram.com/youthcatalog_id/",
        "iconlink": "http://atmoweb.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/listdummy.jpg"
    }
]
```

but now i have problem, list of data that i have filtered, they don't display but they still showing up in html, i mean like this.

[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UisMT.png)

i mark the data that showing up in html they don't display. how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're looping on the `<ion-slide>` so regardless of whether or not the `*ngIf` is evaluated to true, the `<ion-slide>` will display render with empty content.  You can use the `*ngFor` on an `<ng-container>` to loop through the items.  Then add the `*ngIf` to the `<ion-slide>`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-slide *ngIf="item.status === 'marketplace'">
    <div >
      ...
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ng-container>
```

> https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/

---

Another option is to filter the items by calling a method in you ts file.

#### items-list.component.html

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of getMarketplaceItems(items)">
  <div >
    ...
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

#### items-list.component.ts

```
getMarketplaceItems(items) {
  return items.filter(item => item.status === 'marketplace');
}
```

Comment: sorry, i made mistake i change the code. can you solve it?

Comment: it works! the unnecessary data is not being rendered, but styling gone LOL it's ok thank's a lot